# Заполнить массив собственного класса своей функцией

Tags: c#, массивы, классы, объекты

Добрый день. Не могу понять как можно заполнить массив своего класса при помощи функции. Задача такова - заполнить массив учениками.

```
 class Uchenik
        {
            public string name;
            public string surname;
            public string kod;


            public void Registracija()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Surname:");
                surname = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Kod:");
                kod = Console.ReadLine();

            }


            } 

     class Klass
            {

                public string nazvanie;
                public static int kolichestvo;
                public Uchenik[] ucheniki = new Uchenik[kolichestvo];



                public void Registracija()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite nazvanie klasa:");
                    nazvanie = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite kolichestvo uchenikov ");
                    kolichestvo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Uchenik uch= new uchenik();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ucheniki.Length; i++)
                    {
                        ucheniki[i] = uch.Registracija();

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 6):

Код

```
public static int kolichestvo;
public Uchenik[] ucheniki = new Uchenik[kolichestvo];
```

неправильный. Массив `ucheniki` при изменении `kolichestvo` не будет волшебным образом пересоздан. А значит, он будет создан вначале, когда `kolichestvo == 0`. Это явно не то, чего вы хотели.

Пишите так:

```
public static int kolichestvo;
public Uchenik[] ucheniki;

public void Registracija()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite nazvanie klasa:");
    nazvanie = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite kolichestvo uchenikov ");
    kolichestvo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    // теперь количество известно, можно создавать массив
    ucheniki = new Uchenik[kolichestvo];

    for (int i = 0; i < ucheniki.Length; i++)
    {
        // создаём каждый раз нового ученика
        Uchenik uch = new Uchenik();
        // регистрируем его
        uch.Registracija();
        // и добавляем в список
        ucheniki[i] = uch;
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас глаза и сердце не болели, когда Вы переписывали эти прекрасные названия из вопроса?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Ещё как! Это стоило мне флакона успокоительного :)

Comment: Плюс Вам за стойкость и мужество хД